# Having trouble with popup in Facebook application

Tags: javascript, facebook, html

I'm trying to make a popup on my site to function as a content locker if the Facebook user on my site hasn't allowed our application on Facebook. I believe the code I have for my popup is written well, as it functions properly by itself. The Facebook code that checks to see if the user is logged in or not also works properly independently. I'm having trouble combining the Facebook javascript and my DIVs. My popup works until I try and put the DIVs for the popup inside my `else` or `else if` statments.

Am I able to put these divs inside the javascript `else if` and `else` statements? The following DIVs are what I'm trying to put inside the statements:

```
<div class="overlay"><div class="overlay-content"></div></div>
```

I also tried displaying the divs by putting them inside `document.write` but it doesn't help me either.

My code can be [found here](http://pastebin.com/TdiA1x8T), or pasted from there:

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
if (response.status === 'connected'){
    document.write("Looks like you're logged into Facebook and our app :)");
    // the user is logged in and connected to your
    // app, and response.authResponse supplies
    // the user’s ID, a valid access token, a signed
    // request, and the time the access token 
    // and signed request each expire
    var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
    var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
} 
else if (response.status === 'not_authorized'){
    <div class="overlay"><div class="overlay-content"></div></div>
    // the user is logged in to Facebook, 
    //but not connected to the app
}
else{
    <div class="overlay"><div class="overlay-content"></div></div> 
    // the user isn't even logged in to Facebook.
}
});
</script>
```

Comment: Argh, seen this only after answering already – you’ve asked about this two times before already, http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/11751886/whats-an-easy-way-to-show-a-popover-based-on-if-if-else-statements - http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/11788791/coding-a-popup-over-my-content-that-checks-facebook-login-status – **please**, get some basic knowledge of the techniques, so that you can at least understand the answers you’re getting here on SO – or hire a professional, if you still have no …ing clue!

Answer (score 0):

> My popup works until I try and put the DIVs for the popup inside my else or else if statments.

That’s because you’re just mixing JS and HTML code, which is not possible in that way. (Please get some basic knowledge of how these things work, because that attempt shows a clear lack of that basic knowledge!)

> I also tried displaying the divs by putting them inside document.write but it doesn't help me either.

That’s not a promising approach either. document.write, called after the initial rendering of the document, will *replace* the current document. So this is also not what you want.

The solution is quite simple – have the overlaying DIV element in your HTML code at any time; and then, after checking login, just make it invisible by either setting it’s style to display:none (directly or by manipulating it’s class, for example), or remove it from the DOM completely.

And again, please get some *basic* knowledge about the techniques you want to use.

Comment: @CBroe... thank you so much! Sorry for the less than appropriate actions taken on my part.